# Scraping hockey data with IMPORTHTML in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please suggest a formula that would **help to output a list of player statistics from all 69 pages on the KHL website, not just the first page**. Maybe it is a case for IMPORTXML usage. Link to the site and the current IMPORTHTML formula inside the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KSVO3jBqAX3CressOeIDu8Hhub8eyYDrwv4iF_17HL4/edit#gid=0

```
=IMPORTHTML(A1,"table",1)
```

Comment: I wish you scraping people would learn how to spell

Comment: `Maybe it is a case for IMPORTXML usage. Link to the site and the current IMPORTHTML formula inside the file:` Quite possibly. Would you please edit the question to include a summary of your research on this topic, and also include details about how you tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I agree with @[Tedinoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330560) that the question needs improvement. This [URL](https://en.khl.ru/stat/players/1217/skaters/?schedule=1217&SHOWALL_1=1) contains all the players. However, trying it with `IMPORTHTML` or `IMPORTXML` gives this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LpfT.png) as expected. Instead, you can get the data for each table, like this [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHSaj.png) of the second page, with this being its [URL](https://en.khl.ru/stat/players/1217/skaters/?schedule=1217&PAGEN_1=2).

Comment: Thank you, this solution is what I need. But how how did you know that "?schedule=1217&PAGEN_1=2" structure is fits here?

Comment: I did some trial and error to get the link structure. After going to the web address you shared, I right-clicked `2` under the first page's table and selected `Copy link address`. That's when I got this [URL](https://en.khl.ru/stat/players/1217/skaters/?schedule=1217&section=skaters&PAGEN_1=2), but when I tried it with `IMPORTHTML` and `IMPORTXML`, it didn't work. When `&section=skaters` was removed, I saw that it resulted in the same web page, and when I tried it, it worked, so I shared the information here.

Comment: Let me go ahead and rephrase my comments to be an answer to this question since you mentioned that `this solution is what I need`. That way, other community members who stumble upon this post may know this information. Feel free to accept the answer and upvote it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you'll encounter the error `Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.` with the amount of data you'd like to import from this [URL](https://en.khl.ru/stat/players/1217/skaters/?schedule=1217&SHOWALL_1=1), you can get the data for each table instead and use `IMPORTHTML` or `IMPORTXML` like this:

[image]

To get the link structure that'll work for the formula, like this [URL](https://en.khl.ru/stat/players/1217/skaters/?schedule=1217&PAGEN_1=2) for the second table in the website you shared, you may do the following:

1. Right-click the page number of the data you'd like to import > **Copy link address**.
2. Paste the link to the Google Sheet that you have, and then use `IMPORTHTML` or `IMPORTXML`. *Note: If you encounter an error with the formula, remove `&section=skaters`, which worked for me.*